# Sending POST data to WebView with strings that don't work with GET

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I'm trying to send data to the url I'm opening in Webview, the data is another url string with parameters but it seems the way Webview uses post is just as a string of parameters like in a url, so this wont work for me. Here's how it looks.

`<WebView source={{uri: 'https://mypage.com/index.php', method:'POST, body: 'PARAM1=1stparam&PARAM2=http://example.app?cat=mau&dog=pug''}}
  />`

Am I missing something or is there another way of passing this data?

Comment: There is an error with your body params. check the end of the string. You have a single quote which is causing errors

Comment: and missing a ' on POST